# how to import csv with comma data in column in azure sql database using bcp

Tags: sql-server, azure, import

how to import CSV with comma data in a column in the azure SQL database using bcp.
I am trying to import CSV file using this below command import all data but exclude data with the comma in column.

```
bcp demo_db.dbo.test1 in C:\rnd_csv_test.csv -S server_name -U user -P password -q -c -t ,
```

Please help...

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: Try with add database name -d demo_db. i.e. `bcp test1 in C:\rnd_csv_test.csv -S server_name -d demo_db -U user -P password -q -c -t ,`

Comment: I am trying the same as given by you, but same result

Comment: find error: SQLState = 22005, NativeError = 0 Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Invalid character value for cast specification

Answer (score 0):

I tried this with bcp command and get the same error.

[image]

Error:
[image]

I also tried using the import data in SSMS. But the data in csv file will become like this:
[image]

We all could not load the data completely. According my experience, it's not supported.

One of the way is you can re-export the csv file with other column delimiter. For example, using the ";", it works ok.

[image]

Another way is  you can use the text `Replace` function, but it's not a good way if you have large data in the csv file.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: We want to automate this process then how can we do this. using stored procedure

Comment: As far as I know, It's hard to be achieved even using stored procedure. An extra comma is equivalent to an extra column. The column which has the comma data will be split into two columns by comma. Each comma is treated as a delimiter by default in your csv file.

Comment: Hi @S.gupta, if my answer helps, could you please accept or vote it? Thanks and have a good day. Still hope others can give you more suggestions.